# Iterate over two variables in bash

Tags: bash, shell

In my script I need to create tags from specific refs on specific branches using git server API. What I'm trying to achive

I have two variables

```
branches="feature develop hotfix"

refs="ref-for feature ref-for-develop ref-for-hotfix"
```

And I'm trying create api call with schema like this

```
curl -X POST <gitserverurl><feature><ref-for-feature><new-tag-name>
```

And so on for other branches. I've started to test loops ( `for i in var` ), but got nowhere. How could I archive this in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using *arrays* for the branches and features, and then looping over the indices of one of the arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

branches=("feature" "develop" "hotfix")

refs=("ref-for feature" "ref-for-develop" "ref-for-hotfix")

for i in "${!branches[@]}"; do
  curl -X POST "<gitserverurl>${branches[i]}${refs[i]}<new-tag-name>"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! In a meantime I've found how to create array from single variable t="1,2,3"
d="4,5,6"
a=($(echo "$t" | tr ',' '\n'))
b=($(echo "$d" | tr ',' '\n'))
for i in {0..3}
do
echo "${a[i]} ${b[i]}" 
done Output: 1 4
2 5
3 6

Comment: @TheD3V in bash, it would be more idiomatic to use a construct like `IFS=, read -a a <<<"$t"` to turn delimited strings to arrays